# hi , i am not able to get last 10 element in yii , using findby sql

Tags: yii

```
 public function getGet($nid)
       {
          $sensor = $this->findBySql("select * from tbl_sensor where stype=4 and nid=$nid order by timestamp desc limit 10;");

        if ($sensor == NULL)
        return "NULL";
        return $sensor->sdata;
       }
```

Comment: what are you getting for `var_dump($sensor);`?

Comment: string(1) "0" string(1) "0" string(1) "0"  string(3) "473"

Comment: are you having this code in model?

Comment: yes , i have put it in my sensor model.

Comment: when i run in terminal ,sqlite >select * from tbl_sensor where stype=4 and nid=$nid order by timestamp desc limit 10; it gave me last 10 element but it not gave when i used in model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code.

```
echo "select * from tbl_sensor where stype=4 and nid=$nid order by timestamp desc limit 10";
$res= Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from tbl_sensor where stype=4 and nid=$nid order by timestamp desc limit 10")->queryAll();

//print_r($res); // will return array of result.
// to check query, print the query executed.

return $res;
```

Comment: Kumar , still am not got result ,

Comment: what are you getting for answer?

Comment: throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: {error}',

Comment: public function getCurrGraphH($nid)
 {

  $res= Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from tbl_sensor where stype=4 and nid=$nid order by timestamp desc limit 10")->queryAll();
  
 }

Comment: Where did you get this error? in this function or outside? you didn't return $res.

Comment: return var_dump($res->sdata);
or return array($res->sdata); but i still got a error, plz help to get out..

Comment: public function getCurrGraphH($nid)
 {

  $res= Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from tbl_sensor where stype=4 and nid=$nid order by timestamp desc limit 10")->queryAll();
   //return var_dump($res->sdata);
                  return array($res->sdata);  
 }

Comment: are you sure you are passing `$nid` to this function?

Comment: where are you calling this function? In controller or view? Add those line of code as well

Comment: yes , which i call in another model                            public function getCurrGraphH()
        {
  $data = Sensor::model()->getCurrGraphH($this->nid);
  return $data;
 }

Comment: i added code to check the last query executed. Now you can see the query. just copy and paste it in phpmyadmin sql query and run to check query is correct or not

Comment: Thanks , another thing is that i am not able to return  in explode ,

Comment: Already you are returning as array. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: now i understand  thanks , kumar can you tell me how to return sdata in float ,like 210 => 21.0 , 345 = 34.5 $sensor = Yii::app()->zdb->createCommand("select * from tbl_sensor where stype=2 and nid=$nid order by timestamp desc limit 10")->queryAll();
            if($sensor) {
            return $sensor->sdata/10;
          } else {
         return null;
          }   error it showing Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: `queryAll()` will returns result in multi-dimensional array. Just do `print_r($sensor);`.  You can see what is inside `$sensor`.